# Generate and manage CSS Sprites directly in an ASP.NET solution

Tags: asp.net, css, webforms, css-sprites

Do you know some good tools to generate and manage CSS Sprites directly in an ASP.NET WebForm solution?

Comment: Check this NuGet package: [Asp.NetSpritesGenerator](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NuGetPackageOfTheWeek1ASPNETSpriteAndImageOptimization.aspx) or this [post](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/cssspritegenerator.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

May be you are looking for this

http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/65787

Refer http://weblogs.asp.net/mikaelsoderstrom/archive/2010/08/10/generate-css-sprites-in-asp-net.aspx you will get an idea how to Generate CSS Sprites in ASP.NET

Answer (score 1):

Check out http://RequestReduce.com which will automaticlly sprite CSS background images in any asp.net page. It also merges and minifies your css and javascript.